# Safari: kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 1 on local (HTML) files

Tags: safari

I keep a lot of local HTML files on my machine, including my home page.  Whenever I first open Safari, and often when going to any local file, I will receive an error.  Hitting refresh (or, for the home page, the home button again) fixes the problem... until the next time you try to go anywhere.

Usually opening a link in a new tab prevents this from occurring; opening a link in the same tab almost always sees the error.

I realize "wait for Apple to get around to fixing it" is a valid answer; I also realize "use a different browser" is a valid answer.  I'm hoping, instead, for a setting change I can make, or HTML tag I can add to my metric badger-load of files, to prevent this error without swapping browsers or waiting for an update (since it's already been happening for quite some time).

**The error:**

> **Safari Can't Open the Page**
>
> Safari can't open the page.  The error is "The operation couldn't be completed.
>
> (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 1.)" (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork:1)

**Some potentially useful information:**

macOS Mojave Version 10.14.4  (On a desktop, if that matters.)

Safari Version 12.1 (14607.1.40.1.4)

Comment: Some Googling on `kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error 1` indicates that it may be a file permissions error ... somewhere. That's all I got.

Comment: Interesting, I'm getting the same thing on Catalina PB 4 with Safari 13.0 Have you been able to figure anything out yet?

Comment: You might have some luck with this solution: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/366448/safari-giving-kcferrordomaincfnetwork-error-303-when-visiting-a-site

Comment: @MattSephton I'll check it when I get home today!

Comment: I must have a different version of Safari - or different permissions - because that option didn't exist.  I poked around for a bit with similar settings, but wasn't able to change the issue.  I'll spend more time over the next few days (as time permits) investigating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue with my homepage which is stored locally on my mac. Putting the HTML files in the Applications folder seemed to solve the problem.

I know it's not the best solution but at least I don't get an error anymore when opening a new tab.

Comment: Just putting the home page here - and none of the other pages - seems to have fixed the problem.  As you stated, it's sub-optimal... but better than hitting refresh every time I hit home.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue. However, I also use Microsoft Edge and at some point, Edge asked me for permission and it worked again, though in Safari it didn't.

So I compared permissions and found out Edge got some permissions Safari never asked for. Giving Safari the permission "Full disk access" within **System Preferences** > **Security and Privacy** > **Privacy** tab> **Full Disk Access** , click the '+' to **Add Software**, then locate Safari to add to the list. This solved the issue for me.